# Whether the sentence is the conditional sentence type II

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If you knew the trouble I've had with this one.

I'd like to know whether the sentence is the conditional sentence type II. The
sentence is taken from RD MAY 2013.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the *If* at the beginning, this is not a true conditional construction. (In fact it's not even a formal sentence, since there's no apodosis [consequence or *then* clause], just a subordinate protasis [condition or *if* clause].) It's a sort of **rhetorical** conditional, like a rhetorical question. On the surface, it leaves the hearer to infer the consequence from the context:

> If you knew the trouble I've had with this one *[you'd feel sorry for me]*.
>   If you knew the trouble I've had with this one *[you'd regret asking]*.
>   If you knew the trouble I've had with this one *[you'd stop badgering me]*.

And in fact it may imply no particular consequence. It amounts to an 'optative subjunctive'—a clause employing syntactic and morphological forms implying a wish or desire. It's equivalent to

> I wish you to understand how much trouble I've had with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional sentence type 2 is eg If I had the necessary money I would buy a house. You have a main clause (I would buy) and a subclause (If I had, past subjunctive for unreal condition).

In your example there is no main clause. You have only a relative clause added to "trouble": the trouble (that) I've had with this one. The sentence is a kind of exclamation. Of course, the sentence is not complete as StoneyB says. You could add "then you would judge differently". With this clause added you get a conditional sentence of type 2.

Comment: I think it is not a relative clause. According to you, the verb should be "had had".